# How to host Webpack DevServer in a custom path

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to configure webpack devserver **to run in `http://localhost:8080/myProject`**

*instead of the root path `localhost:8080`*

I already tried to configure

`public: 'https://localhost:8080/myProject'`,

and

`publicPath: '/myProject/'`

settings but I can't make it work.

I also tried to play with the `proxy` settings but that seems wrong.

The reason why i need this change it's because the api server sends a cookie with `path=/myProject`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to emulate some API or do you want to get your front-end app at /myProject? If you want front-end at /myProject you don't need to edit a devserver, you just need to configure [output](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) in webpack.config.js:

```
output: {
  publicPath: '/myProject',
},
```

For emulating API you can use [onBeforeSetupMiddleware](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveronbeforesetupmiddleware) in webpack.config.js:

```
devServer: {
  port: 3000,
  https: true,
  onBeforeSetupMiddleware: function (devServer) {
    devServer.app.get('/myProject', function (req, res) {
      res.json({
        message: 'some data from API'
      });
    });
  },
},
```

Comment: The ideia was to get the frontend app at `/myProject`
I no longer have that project but thanks for the answer