# white blank when i deploy my website on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages, router

im struggling deploying my website on github page always getting a white blank

im using `HashRouter`

```
    <HashRouter basename="/drippy-e-commerce">
    <AuthProvider>
      <ProductsContext>
        <Navbar />
        
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup/>} />      
          <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin/>} />  
          <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<ProductPage/>} />  
          <Route path="/addresses" element={<Addresses/>} />  
          <Route path="/accessories" element={<Accessories/>} />  
          <Route path="/shoes" element={<Shoes/>} />  
          <Route path="/jackets" element={<Jackets/>} />  
          <Route path="/sales" element={<Sales/>} />  
            
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
        <Chat/>
          </ProductsContext>
        </AuthProvider>
    </HashRouter>
```

and here is my `package.json`

`

```
{
  "homepage": "./",
  "name": "drippy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist -b new-gh-page",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chatbot-kit": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react-app-env": "^1.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

`
i have tried the

```
'homepage' : "https://ziaddalii.github.io/drippy-e-commerce/"
```

but it didnt work .. and tried

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
```

but some suggested to change my `homepage` to "./" and to change the name of the deploy but it didnt work either..

some suggested to just wait but i waited for a whole day and it didnt work

and i just get this error on my page

> GET https://ziaddalii.github.io/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

and here is my github code
https://github.com/ziaddalii/drippy-e-commerce
and my website
https://ziaddalii.github.io/drippy-e-commerce/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to host Webpack DevServer in a custom path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374534/how-to-host-webpack-devserver-in-a-custom-path)

Comment: i have my public path set to "/" i dont understand if i need to change it and what to change it to?? cause in the question you sent he is not trying to deploy it on github?

Answer (score 0):

solved by changing my `bundle.js` publicPath to `publicPath: '/drippy-e-commerce/'` in my `webpack.config.js`